# empty button because of a checkbox

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, ionic2

Since a ngIf and a ngFor cannot cohabit, I put a ng-container to make the loop. But sinci I did that anything isn't working without any logic. Here is the code :

view

```
<ion-list *ngIf="listfavoris else loading">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let favoris of listfavoris">
      <button ion-item ion-long-press [interval]="500" (onPressing)="showModeCheckList(favoris)" (click)="openDocument(favoris)" *ngIf="favoris.shouldbedisplayed || ModeCheckList">
        <h2>{{favoris.Nom}}</h2>
        <h3>{{favoris.Description}}</h3>
        <p *ngIf="favoris.Synchro == 1"><ion-icon name="sync" color="vert"></ion-icon> Dernière synchronisation le {{favoris.DateSynchro}}</p>
        <p *ngIf="favoris.Synchro == 0">Pas synchronisé</p>
        <ion-checkbox color="bleu" item-right [checked]="favoris.Checked" (ionChange)="toggleFavoris(favoris)"  *ngIf="ModeCheckList"></ion-checkbox>
      </button>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-list>
```

controller

```
    showModeCheckList(favoris:FavorisModel) {
        this.vibration.vibrate(100);
        this.ModeCheckList = true;
        this.toggleFavoris(favoris);
    }

    toggleFavoris(favoris: FavorisModel): void {
        favoris.Checked = !favoris.Checked;
        if (favoris.Checked) {
            this.NbFavorisSelect++;
        }
        else {
            this.NbFavorisSelect--;
        }
    }
```

Some buttons should be displayed at any time and some other should be displayed only in ModeCheckList.

- If I let the code like that, buttons that should be displayed are always displayed correctly, but when I enter the ModeCheckList, the newly displayed buttons are empty (h2 not showing...) only an empty button with the checkbox appears
- If I remove the checkbox completely, all elements are correctly displayed at any time (but I need the checkbox)
- If I remove the ngif and put the ngfor in the button tag, the problem dissapears (but I need the ngif)
- I cannot put ngif outside the ngfor because the test is about current loop element.
- If I remove only the ngif from the checkbox, all elements are empty and when I enter the ModeChecklist, I get this error

  ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'
- If I remove ngif and ion-change from the checkbox, all elements are always empty buttons

I don't understand anything, what's the problem with the checkbox ?

Comment: Instead of using ngIf you can try using [hidden] attribute so you don't need to work around using ng-container. Also why using ng-container instead of a simple div?

Comment: could you provide a plunker example?

Comment: thanks SAJ, it works well with [hidden].
Still I would like to know why it doesn't work, i am currently making a plunker.
Suraj Rao : yes datas are correct, even stranger if I put a console.log(favori) in the togglefavori method, the favori is returned well with all correct datas

Comment: Here is the plunker (discovered by the way that removing "ion-item" from the button make the problem dissapear.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/QnetmWgwVgEQULwPFcyw?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work with the following code:

```
<ion-list>
<ng-container *ngFor="let favoris of listfavoris">
  <button ion-item *ngIf="ModeCheckList || favoris.shouldbedisplayed">
    <ion-label>
      <h2>{{favoris.Nom}}</h2>
      <h3>{{favoris.Description}}</h3>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox item-end [checked]="favoris.Checked" (ionChange)="toggleFavoris(favoris)"  *ngIf="ModeCheckList"></ion-checkbox>
  </button>
</ng-container>
</ion-list>
<button (click)="showModeCheckList(favoris)">toggle checklist mode</button>
```

If you don't specify an `<ion-label>` inside of an item all the content of the item is placed inside a label, maybe this is causing the problem. Some binding was not beeing applied to your `h` tags or the checkbox was overwriting them. In fact i can't explain much of why this happened, but i've faced problems with `ion-item` that i solved placing an empty `ion-label` and the rest of the content inside a div with `item-end`or `item-content` attribute.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with **ng-container**. Why do use ng-container here when you can simply use a div

`<ng-container>` is a logical container that can be used to group nodes but is not rendered in the DOM tree as a node.

`<ng-container>` is rendered as an HTML comment.
so this angular template :

```
<div>
    <ng-container>foo</ng-container>
<div>
```

will produce this kind of output :

```
<div>
    <!--template bindings={}-->foo
<div>
```

Try changing it to div and give it a try

Comment: oh forget to tell, already tried replacing ng-container by simple div, the result is the same